# how to get live geo location in react native

Tags: android, react-native, geolocation

I've added MapView into my app but i want to initialize the region with the current user's live location, The code on the emulator changes the initial region to the location of google's HQ in CA (I know that's normal and i can change the emulator's location in settings) but on my own phone, the initial region doesn't change at all.

using the GEO location api preferred by react native:

```
const [region, setRegion] = useState({
    latitude: -1.951670,
    longitude: 30.157518,
    latitudeDelta: 0.015,
    longitudeDelta: 0.015,
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    let currentLocation = true;
    let newRegion = { latitude: null, longitude: null, latitudeDelta: null, longitudeDelta: null };
    newRegion.longitudeDelta = region.longitudeDelta;
    newRegion.latitudeDelta = region.latitudeDelta;
    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition((info) => {
      newRegion.latitude = info.coords.latitude
      newRegion.longitude = info.coords.longitude;
    },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error.code, error.message);
      },
      { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 15000, maximumAge: 10000 }
    )
    
    //To make sure no null is still present in the newReion obj
    for (var key in newRegion) {
      if (!newRegion[key]) {
        currentLocation = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (currentLocation) {
      setRegion(newRegion);
    }
  }, [])

//Map view implementation:
<MapView
        provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
        ref={map => _map = map}
        showsUserLocation={true}
        style={styles.map}
        initialRegion={initialPosition}
        onRegionChangeComplete={(region) => setInitialPosition(region)}
      />
```

Comment: Have you tried showsUserLocation={true} in mapView?

Comment: Yeah, The same issue persists

Comment: Strange, Because showsUserLocation={true} will show the user current location on the map as we see in google maps without extra work. Check your mapView implementation.

Comment: @rishikesh_07 edited the code to add the map view implementation.